# Smoke in a bottle - smoke not colliding

Tags: smoke-simulation

I would like to simulate smoke swirling in a "bottled", enclosed sphere.

The smoke interacts and collides with the outside sphere, when emitted from outside, but not inside.

I also tried to emit the smoke into a concave hull (a capped sphere with thickness added) and the smoke just travels straight through.

How can I get this to work ? Are there any extra settings to switch on to get smoke to interact with concave or enclosed objects ? Or are they not compatible yet ?

Answer (score -1):

I ran in to this problem. I was trying to simulate smoke in a sphere. I am using 2.83.

Eevee materials are not currently capable of rendering volumetrics other than the bounding box of an object. [Look Under Volume Objects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/limitations.html#materials)

If you are using cycles and having this problem then I believe how I fixed it was by selecting *Is Planar* under the *Effector* settings for the object that you want as the limit.